# javascript this returns unknown property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I just wrote that piece of code and get an error at the alert part telling me, that  this.words is not definded.
I guess the jquery part changes the "this" value, because at where the comment is, I can access the array.

Now I stuck, because I don't want to make the words property global (what makes it run).
So I want to ask you for a way to fix the problem while keeping in "OOP" style.

```
function game()
{
    this.difficulty = 0;
    this.mode = 0;
    this.words = new Array();

    this.loadWords = function()
    {
        //request word pool
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"word.php",
            data:{mode:this.mode, difficulty:this.difficulty}
        }).done(function(html) {
            alert(this.words.length);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As is, `this` represents `window` which is global.  What are you intending exactly?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a scoping issue. `this` no longer refers to the game object within the `.done` function. Try

```
this.loadWords = function()
{
    var that = this;
    //request word pool
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"word.php",
        data:{mode:this.mode, difficulty:this.difficulty}
    }).done(function(html) {
        alert(that.words.length);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function Game()
{
    this.difficulty = 0;
    this.mode = 0;
    this.words = new Array();
    this.wordsLoaded = $.proxy(this.wordsLoaded, this);
}

var method = Game.prototype;

method.loadWords = function() {

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"word.php",
        data:{mode:this.mode, difficulty:this.difficulty},
        success: this.wordsLoaded
    });

};

method.wordsLoaded = function() {
    alert( this.words.length );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` is changed in your `` `done() `` handler so it is no longer your object. You can fix it by saving away the copy of `this` into another variable like this:

```
function game()
{
    this.difficulty = 0;
    this.mode = 0;
    this.words = new Array();

    this.loadWords = function()
    {
        var self = this;
        //request word pool
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"word.php",
            data:{mode:this.mode, difficulty:this.difficulty}
        }).done(function(html) {
            alert(self.words.length);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the game function internally by doing something like:

`var _self = game;`

That way you do `_self.difficulty`, `_self.words.length`, etc... and they will be able to access it.

Comment: using `self` in this way is not recommended, as `self` is by default an alias for `window`. Reassigning `self` may have undesired effects. Better to use `that`, `_this`, etc

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to type _self (it's what I normally use), you are definitely right though!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

for more ideas on private, protected and public in javascript, but here is a solution:

**Untested code**

```
function game() {
    var difficulty = 0;
    var mode = 0;
    var words = [];
    this.loadWords = function()
    {
        //request word pool
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"word.php",
            data:{mode:this.mode, difficulty:this.difficulty}
        }).done(function(html) {
            alert(this.words.length);
        });
    }
}
```

You would want a getter for `words` also, but basically there is one way to initialize it, by calling the function and any other access is through the getter.

**Untested code**

function game() {
        var difficulty = 0;
        var mode = 0;
        var words = [];
        var that = this;
        this.loadWords = function()
        {
            //request word pool
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"word.php",
                data:{mode:that.mode, difficulty:that.difficulty}
            }).done(function(html) {
                alert(this.words.length);
            });
        }
    }

I added a `that` variable and set it to `this`, to help enclose that value, but in the ajax call it may be enough to call the `mode` variable directly, but it may be needed to use `that`.  Also, the `this` before the function may be an issue, not certain, I would need to use a debugger to see what is actually happening and see what to use actually.

I had missed the `this` inside the .ajax call, which was the problem initially.

Comment: Try removing the 'this', but I would need to test and see what happens, but I won't get a chance to do that for a couple of days.